# Using Azure Mobile Services Code First Generated Context class in another project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Windows Azure Mobile Services app that has a Code First generated database. The connection string (for when run locally) looks like this:

```
<add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\<database_name.mdf;Initial Catalog=<database_name>;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I created a new Console App project, referencing the Mobile Services project, and copied this connection string to the App.config file

In Program.Main() I created a new instance of the Context class from the Designer in the Mobile Services project. But when I run the Console App, and try to access one of the DbSets made public by the Context, I get the following exception:

```
"An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details."
```

With an inner exception of:

```
"The underlying provider failed on Open."
```

Which in turn has an inner exception of:

```
"Cannot attach the file 'C:\\...\\<database_name>.mdf' as database '<database_name>'."
```

If I remove the AttachDbFilename part of the connection string in the Console App, I get the following exception at the same point in the code:

```
"Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.<Table_Name>'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.<Table_Name>' before creating another"
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would be trying to create this new clustered index when there already appears to be one?

Or any ideas what connection string I should use just to get a normal read/write connection to the database without it doing anything weird? Is this related to database initialization?

Edit: I've had a bit more of a play around with this, this morning. I can get it working without exceptions if I remove the inheritance of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData" from my model classes, so this appears to be pretty significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've just battled through this and got it working. Gonna type this up in case it helps anyone one day.

So the problem is something to do with the fact that my Code First model classes were inheriting from EntityData. As I said in my edit above, removing this inheritance does appear to fix the problem. I think this is because the EntityData class has both a property with a [Key] attribute and a separate property with a [Index(IsClustered = true)] attribute. Because you can't have more than one Clustered Index in a table, the database initialization fails. In the default Azure Mobile Services project, there must be some magic that means this doesn't happen somewhere - but from a separate project you get the "Cannot create more than one clustered index on table" exception.

So what I did was disable Database Initialization in the separate Console App by adding the line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MobileServiceContext>(null);
```

...before the DbContext is instantiated.

This allows me to use the database initialized by the Mobile Services App as an existing database, without attempting to make any changes to it.

I also needed the following AppSetting in the config file of the Console App, in order for it to use the correct Schema Name:

```
<add key="MS_MobileServiceName" value="<CorrectSchemaName>" />
```